# Array of structure type. with pointer inside of structure

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I'm missing something, probably very stupid, but I have no ideas anymore, I need some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct person{
    char name[10];
    int *age;
} PERSON;

int main(){
    int i, n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    PERSON *arr = (PERSON*)calloc(n, sizeof(PERSON));
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        gets(arr[i].name);
        // scanf("%d", arr[i].age);
    }
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%s", arr[i].name);
//          printf("%d", arr[i]->age));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

So, I cannot enter or read the **age** of any structure.
I need a dynamic array of persons and in each person, I need a new dynamic array as well (this is a simplified version of the original code, but the error is same).

I have commented my last tries so you can see how I tried to do it.

Error I get is `[Error] invalid type argument of '->' (have 'PERSON')`.

Comment: Do not use the function `gets`; It has been removed from the standard, and for good reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `age` is a pointer not pointing to any memory. You have to either allocate memory and make that `int*` point to it OR change the structure definition to contain an `int`. Otherwise you were simply passing an indeterminate pointer value to `scanf` - this is undefined behavior. You can do this

```
arr[i].age = malloc(sizeof *arr[i].age);
if(!arr[i].age){
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and then use it in `scanf`. `scanf("%d",arr[i].age);`
Print it

```
printf("%d\n",*arr[i].age);
```

The more natural solution would be to

```
typedef struct person{
    char name[10];
    int age;
} PERSON;
```

And use it accordingly. Then it would be something like

```
scanf("%d",&arr[i].age);
```

and

```
printf("%d\n",arr[i].age);
```

To clarify the error a bit:

```
arr[i]->age
\----/
```

This is a  `PERSON` structure instance over which you apply the `->`, which is why the error.

<sub>Check the return value of `malloc`,`scanf` etc. It would help you detect the error cases that may occur. `gets` is deprecated. Use `fgets` instead.</sub>

Comment: @coderredoc was just trying to amplify, not correcting